# What is the method invoked when I use this method call in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Foo{

        public static void main(String args[]){
            JFrame f=new JFrame();
            f.add("North",new JButton());    //Line 1
            f.add(new JButton(),"North");    //Line 2
            f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The swing API states that the JFrame class contains 5 methods by the name add, inherited from java.awt.Container and another add method inherited from java.awt.Component.

```
**Their signatures are as follows:**

*Inherited from java.awt.Container*

    add(Component)

    add(Component,int)

    add(Component,Object)

    add(Component,Object,int)

    add(String,Component)

*Inherited from java.awt.Component*

    add(java.awt.PopupMenu)
```

I expected in the API there would be two overloaded method with signatures add(Component,String) and add(String,Component). But seeing as that is not the case I assume that Line 1 invokes add(String,Component) and Line 2 invokes add(Component,Object).

Also, can anyone give me an explanation about how the invoked methods are implemented. I tried to figure this out by looking at the source of the API but the method invocation chains are like a labyrinth and I could use the guidance of someone who's been there before.

Comment: Eventaully, they all call [`Container#addImpl(Component, Object, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29), expect `add(PopupMenu)`

Comment: You are rigth that `add(Component, Object)` is the only candidate overload here. Also, you are right that methods that do nothing but call another method are quite common in Java.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Well, my question is that I'm capable of using the swing API to get things done but clueless and curious about how the swing library is actually implemented.

Comment: It is not specific question: "how the swing library is actually implemented", I don't see any specific one in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventaully, they all call [`Container#addImpl(Component, Object, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29), expect `add(PopupMenu)`

- `add(Component)` calls `addImpl(comp, null, -1)`
- `add(String, Component)` calls `addImpl(comp, name, -1)`
- `add(Component, int)` calls `addImpl(comp, null, index)`
- `add(Component, Object)` calls `addImpl(comp, constraints, -1)`
- `add(Component, Object, int)` calls `addImpl(comp, constraints, index)`

`addImpl` does a lot of work...

It makes sure;

- That the component is been added to it self
- That the component isn't a type `Window` (as you can't add windows to components)
- That the component's graphics configuration is the same
- That the component isn't already contained within an existing container, and removes it if it is
- That the component is been added within a valid index range (if `index` > -1)

It then...

- Adds the component to a list of components been managed by this container
- Calls the component's `addNotify` method (if the container is realized on the screen)
- Notifies the layout manager of the newly added component
- Notifies any listeners about a container event (`componentAdded`) and hierarchy event (`hierarchyChanged`)

**Extra**

The "add" methods are decorators.  They supply a number of entry methods that filter down to a single method, which is intended to make the live of the developer simpler based on the context of there work.